Unable to activate Gnome Shell Extensions
I have Gnome Shell Extension Manager installed. When I install an extension, such as ArcMenu, I am unable to activate it due to the slider being grayed out.
Things I have tried:

restarting computer
uninstalling and reinstalling Gnome Tweaks, Extension Manager
activating extensions through the terminal
all steps suggested at this Ask Ubuntu, including removing any existing user extensions from ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/, removing "ding@rastersoft.com" from extensions folder.
using other extensions, including "Apps Menu"

I appreciate any assistance.


Looking at the extension from Ubuntu 22.04, I see that ArcMenu is listed as an Unmaintained project and that all related repositories have been officially archived.
In Extension Manager is is listed as Unsupported.
As for the others, this Ask Ubuntu Question may provide a solution.
